# Switch to another subdomain in django on a click of a button

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-hosts

I am actually having issues with template link of a button to point to my subdomain which actually if I enter it manually on a browser, it works just fine. I need something like this

```
{% load hosts %}
<a href="{% host_url 'homepage' host 'www' %}">Home</a>
```

But it doesn't work if i place the code above on a button. Am I missing anything?. Appreciate the help guys

Comment: Check the HOSTS_URLCONF and ROOT_URLCONF settings to ensure they are appropriately set in your Django settings file.

Comment: they are appropriately set in settings. its working when you enter the subdomain link in a browser yourself. but can't place the link on a button in Django Template to be clicked.

Comment: @Transformer if you use named routes, then you need to specify the tag: url.              <a href="{% url 'homepage' %}">Home</a>

Comment: @inquirer, Yes of course but it isn't working.